# Why my request session lose data view to another view in auth azure AD?

Tags: python, django, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to integrate my django platform with azure ad authentication, so I followed the following document
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/graph/tutorials/python.

In my project, I can only login to my platform user when the AD login is complete and working, so I'm trying to pass the user through the session to the callback view (which is called as soon as the AD login is complete) , at times it worked but most of the time the session comes completely empty

```py
def sign_in_ad(request, pk):
    request.session.flush()
    # Get the sign-in URL
    user = User.objects.filter(id=pk).first()
    company_azure = CompanyAzureAd.objects.filter(company=user.employee.firm).first()
    sign_in_url, state = get_sign_in_url(company_azure)
    # Save the expected state so we can validate in the callback
    request.session.update({'user_id': pk})
    request.session.update({'auth_state': state})
    request.session.modified = True
    # Redirect to the Azure sign-in page
    return HttpResponseRedirect(sign_in_url)
```

```py
def callback(request):
    user_id = request.session['user_id'] #Error key not exist
    user_platform = User.objects.filter(id=int(user_id)).first()
    company_azure = CompanyAzureAd.objects.filter(company=user_platform.employee.firm).first()
    # Get the state saved in session
    expected_state = ''
    # Make the token request
    url = request.build_absolute_uri(request.get_full_path())
    if "http:" in url:
        url = "https:" + url[5:]
    token = get_token_from_code(url, expected_state, company_azure)

    # Get the user's profile
    user = get_user(token)

    # Save token and user
    store_token(request, token)
    store_user(request, user)
    login(request, user_platform, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
```

I do not understand why the session is empty, there is a better way to perform this integration, I need the user to log into my platform first and then be redirected to the AD, this flow works, the problem is in the last part, when rescuing the user on the platform and authenticate him

This my get_sign_url:

```py
def get_sign_in_url(company_azure):
    company_azure = json.loads(company_azure.keys)
    authority = company_azure['authority']
    authorize_url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{authority}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize'
    # Initialize the OAuth client
    aad_auth = OAuth2Session(
        company_azure['app_id'],
        scope='User.Read email Calendars.Read openid profile',
        redirect_uri='http://localhost:8000/tutorial/callback'
    )
        
    sign_in_url, state = aad_auth.authorization_url(authorize_url, prompt='login')
    return sign_in_url, state
```

Comment: Have you verified whether the session information is present before sending the session from one data view to another view

Comment: Hi @Gustavo are you still looking for any help on this?